# Ошибка "error: package com.badlogic.gdx does not exist"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, libgdx

**Появляется ошибка "error: package com.badlogic.gdx does not exist" при попытке запуска проекта.**

При этом в классах, на которые указывает ошибка - никаких ошибок нет. В проекте использую libGDX.

Кто-то сталкивался с похожим ? Как это фиксить ?

[image: Пример]

Comment: `File/Sync Project with Gradle Files` пробовали?

Comment: Да, после этого никаких ошибок не выдает. То есть все хорошо, везде "OK".
"invalidate caches/restart" тоже делал. Не помогло